# twitter bootstrap carousel caption not matching photo width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have the Twitter Bootstrap carousel working quite well for the most part but my photos are of different widths and the caption on the bottom matches the widest width so when I have photos with less width the caption stays black for the previous width and looks a little unprofessional.  My code is as follows and I was wondering if there is any way to fix this problem so the width always matches the photo.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 offset2">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                  <div class="carousel-inner">

                 <!-- here I loop through and add a bunch of photos -->
                  {% for photo in record_photos %}

                    <div class="active item">
                        <a href="/url"><img src="some-src"></a>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3 class="center-it">some caption</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   {% endfor %}

                  </div>

                  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't put uneven-width-images in a carousel. Also it's not 100% clear what's happening here. "Stays black?"

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned but they are user submitted photos so I don't have control over what sizes they submit.

Comment: I would say that either you get to reformat those photos or a carousel is a wrong tool for that job. I've got some carousel experience. Mine auto-fit items in as you expanded the page and the accumulated margin space was enough to allow it without losing place. I can write a mean carousel that puts up with a lot of BS. But varying widths... really not worth the trouble for the experience the user ultimately ends up with.

Comment: @ErikReppen you make a good point and can you suggest anything that could serve a similar purpose of letting the user go through various photos without just rendering them all on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest picking a span size that will be the optimum size for the photo widths that you have as span will determine the carousel width. Larger images will shrink to the span width. Smaller images you could 'upsize' by placing them in a larger image with a solid (or transparent) background.

Carousel is designed to show images in the span it is in - conceivably you could dynamically alter the width but personally I think the changes would be somewhat visually jarring between images and there would be the back/next button locations to deal with as well.

BTW, note that in your template code above, every item is active. You will need to put some logic into the loop so that only the first loop iteration produces an item with active class

Comment: alrighty thanks for the help.  yeah I took a lot of the jinja2 out just so as not to confuse people without that experience but they all aren't actually active.